# Determine the cardinality of a set X

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $F$ be a field and $G = GL_n(F)$ .For  $g$ $\in$ $G$ ,write $C_g$ = { $hg$$h^{-1}$ $|$   $h$ $\in G$ }.
>
> Let $X$ = { $C_g$ $|$ $g \in G$ , the order of $g$ is 2 } .
> Determine $|X|$.

I am trying that minimal polynomial of $g$ divides $(x^2 -1)$ so minimal polynomial is either $(x^2-1)$ or $(x+1)$. But don't know what to do next.

Comment: Can you solve the problem if $g$ is a diagonal matrix with all entries equal to $1$ or $-1$? Can you reduce the real problem to that special case? (Hint: Jordan canonical form)