# Let $F$ be a field, $G={\rm GL}_n(F)$. For $g\in G$ write $C_g=\{hgh^{-1}:h\in G\}$. Let $X=\{C_g: g\in G, |g|=2\}$. Determine $|X|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $G={\rm GL}_n(F)$. For $g\in G$ write $C_{g} =\{hgh^{-1}:h\in G\}$. Let $X=\{C_g: g\in G, \text{the order of g is 2}\}$. Determine $|X|$.

Using this hint: [Determine the cardinality of a set X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652966/determine-the-cardinality-of-a-set-x)  I have tried to proceed in this way:

**Case 1:** $\text{char}(F)\neq 2$ then the minimal polynomial of $g$ is $m_g(x)=x+1  \ \text{or} \ x^2-1$ then $g$ is diagonalizable with diagonal elements $1$ or $-1$ but there must at least one $-1$. Now let, $g_1\in {\rm GL}_n(F)$ such that $g_1=hgh^{-1}$ i.e. $g_1$ is similar to $g$ so, all the eigenvalues are the same and $X$ contains such $g_1$. Since there is at least one $-1$ which is an eigenvalue of $g$ so same for $g_1$. Since $g$ is a $n\times n$ matrix so $-1$ occupy $n$ places so $|X|=n$.

**Case 2:** $\text{char}(F)= 2$. Then $m_g(x)=x^2-1=(x-1)^2$ So, $g$ is not diagonalizable and it has a Jordan block in the form $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. So, this Jordan block is same for $g_1$.

But now I am stuck that how can I find $|X|$.
Any help in this regard will very much helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can have $1,2,3,\ldots, \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ of those $2 \times 2$ Jordan blocks, so the answer is $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ .

Comment: @user8675309 I have two questions: (1) Fliping the entries of "$N$" means we have to flip $0\to 1$ in the diagonal elements and $1\to 0$ to the off-diagonal elements. Am I right?
(2) I can't understand "subtracting $1$"  . 
I mean if $n=3$ then $g=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ then $g=I + \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Now my question is did you mean filp $0\to 1$ in the diagonal enelemts of $N$ and $1\to 0$ to the off-diagonal of $N$?

Comment: ignore what I said and go with Derek Holt's comment

Comment: @user8675309 Ah! Actually, I was trying to prove Derek Holt's comment using your hints.

Comment: @DerekHolt sir it can be proved by induction. Right?

Comment: This comes from the general theory of Jordan Canonical Forms, but it can be proved directly.